# Timestamp behavior not working

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a field **start_date** that will assume the current timestamp when the data is saved(not updated). The behavior like this:

```
$this->addBehavior('Timestamp', [
    'events' => [
        'Model.beforeSave' => [
            'start_date' => 'new'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

But I think is not filling with the current timestamp because I'm getting this error:

```
'start_date' => [
    (int) 0 => 'This field is required'
]
```

Comment: Man I'm glad I don't have to use Cake anymore.  Well, quick fix looking at the error would be to set a default for the column, in mysql use 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'.  Has added benefit of reflecting changes made directly in the database... maybe you meant 'now', not 'new'?

Comment: @ficuscr this would not help anywas, as it is failing before even getting to to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've subscribed to the `Model.beforeSave` event, so the timestamp is genereated immediately before saving, that is *after* validation and rules checks, hence the error.

If you need to validate this field for whatever reason (normally it shouldn't be necessary), then subscribe to the [**`Mode.beforeRules` event**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforerules) and use the [**rules checker**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#applying-application-rules) to validate the field.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have assured that `start_date` is provided by attached behavior, remove that field from validation rules. That is what I did at least.